# Let $G$ be a group of order $7105$, show that the order of the center of $G$ is divisible by $35$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $5\cdot 7^2 \cdot 29$, show that the order of the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is divisible by $35$.

Now, $G$ contains only a $5$-sylow, $P_5$, and since the conjugacy action of $G/P_5$ on $P_5$ is the trivial homomorphism, then $P_5 \subseteq Z(G)$, so $5$ divides the order of the center.

The number of $7$-sylow could be either $1$ or $29$, in the first case we can conclude as above. What about the second case?

Comment: It may help to use the fact that $G/Z(G)$ being cyclic implies that $G$ must be abelian.

Comment: You mean "the order is divisible by $35$" , right ?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I have used it for the next question of the exercise, that asks to show that if $G$ has one $7-$Sylow then $G$ is abelian. I am trying to figure out how to use it for this :)

Comment: How do you know that the action of $G/P_5$ on $P_5$ by conjugation is trivial? In $S_3$, there is a unique $3$-Sylow subgroup which is cyclic and normal, but the action of $G/P_3$ on $P_3$ by conjugation is not trivial. I would want to see some more words (presumably it's the fact that $|G/P_5|$ and $|\mathrm{Aut}(P_5)|$ have relatively prime order, but you still need to say *something*...)

Comment: By factoring out the central subgroup of order $5$, you can reduce the problem to showing that a group of order $7^2 \cdot 29$ has a central element of order $7$. To do that, note that such a group has a normal Sylow $29$-subgroup, and the automorphism group of a group of order $29$ is cyclic.

Comment: Or rather, the automorphism group of a group of order $29$ has order $28$, which is not divisible by $7^2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I got it, it is because $5$ is the smallest prime that divides the order of $G$, so I can't apply this result for $7-$sylow's

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that the Sylow $7$-subgroup acts trivially on the Sylow $29$-subgroup, because its automorphism group has order divisible by $7$ (but not by $7^2$).

Comment: @DerekHolt so you can't have a trivial kernel, hence if the kernel has order $7$ this means that the cyclic $7$-group lies in the center and we have a central element of order $7$. If the kernel has order $7^2$?

Comment: Are you asking a question? You should be able to complete the details of the proof yourself now.

Comment: The question was answered $7$ days ago and is listed as having no good answer. You either accept the answer, post your own answer or write what else do you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is listed as unanswered. So I decided to post an answer. This $G$ has unique Sylow $29$-subgroup $S$ by the Sylow theorem. So $S$ is normal, $G/S$ has order $5\cdot 49=245$. $G/S$ has unique Sylow $5$-subgroup $T/S$ of order $5$ and unique $7$-subgroup $R/S$ of order $49$. Both $T/S$ and $R/S$ are cyclic, and normal.

Then $T$ has order $5\times 29$, so it has unique normal, hence characteristic, subgroup  $T_1$ of order $5$. Since $T_1$ is characteristic in $T$ which is normal in $G$, $T_1$ is normal in $G$. $G$ acts on $T_1$ by conjugation, but the automorphism group of $T_1$ has order $4$ and $|G|$ is odd, so the action is trivial, and $T_1$ is central in $G$.

Let $R/S$ be generated by s coset $aS$ of order $49$. Then $a$ acts on $S$ by conjugation. The order of the automorphism group of $S$ is $28=4\cdot 7$, so $a^7S$ is an element of order $7$ which must act trivially on $S$. Therefore $b=a^{7\cdot 29}$ must have order $7$ in $G$. Also it centralizes $S$. Let $B=\langle b\rangle$. Then the subgroups $T_1, B, S_1$ form a direct product in $G$ (they pairwise commute elementwise, and the intersection of each of them with the product of the other two is trivial by the Lagrange theorem). Therefore $T_1B$ is a central subgroup of $G$ of order $35$ (here we use the fact that $T_1$ is central $b$ commutes with $a$ and all elements of $S$, hence is central in $G$).